# Vertical Scalling with Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I know that using Instance Group, it is possible to Horizontal Scale (new VM with same configuration). But is there some way to Vertical Scale with Google Compute Engine automatically? Or only manually?

Some other Google Cloud Plataform's service can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the compute services scale vertically. You select the instance size (machine type) and the services scale horizontally by adding more instances of the same type.

Comment: If none of the service offer this feature, the only method is to manually change the size. Note, not all service support easy manual vertical scaling. In some cases you have to launch new larger instances and migrate the services over to the new instances. Kubernetes is an example. For other services, you must stop them, resize and then restart. Resizing vertically usually means moving to an entire new host cluster. It sounds simple, but technically it is not. Also, which dimension do you scale vertically? Disk, CPU, Memory, Network Bandwidth, etc. etc.

Comment: I am making some comparisons between these two methods, so there is no major change in dimensions. I have to stop the instance to scale, right? So would be impossible to scalen without stoping.

Comment: For a VM instance, yes you must stop the instance, resize and then restart.

Comment: Got it. Thank you, saved me a lot of time.